# IDLE isn't opening and reading a text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a text file that will allow me to read multiple lines and have them become capitalised

```
inputFileName = input("Input file name: ")


infile = open(inputFileName, "w+")
infile = open(inputFileName, "a")
infile = open(inputFileName, "r+")


line = infile.readline()
while line != "" :
    line = infile.readline()
    line = line.upper()
    outfile.write(line)

    print(line)

infile.close()
```

When opening it would not give the context of the file itself, even though what I wrote *should* work

Comment: Opening `inputFileName` three times, `outfile` not declared - please give us your real code. This won't even start to run.

Comment: Sure, blame it on IDLE - you're deleting everything in your file with your first call to `open()`.

Comment: `for line in infile: ...` There is rarely a need to call `readline` explicitly.

Comment: this is my real code, and I'm surely not blaming IDLE that's what I'm currently using

Answer (score 1):

as the comments have begun to mention, and in reference to your final statement, this code absolutely *should not* work, for multiple reasons.

1) you open the file three times, for no apparent reason.

2) `outfile` isn't declared, doesn't do anything.

3) when you open a file with `w` it clears the contents of afformentioned file.

firstly fix these issues.

you understand the fundementals, your upper function is fine etc etc.

this is what you must do.

1) dont open the same file 3 times for no reason

2) define `outfile`

3) use `a` instead of `w` so you append rather then delete and write

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
f_name = input("Input file name: ")

with open(f_name, "r+") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()  # get string, split lines
    lines = [l.capitalize() for l in lines]  # capitalize each line
    f.seek(0)  # move the cursor to the beginning
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))  # join the lines and write to the same file
```

Comment: Don't just give code that works. by doing this they will be stuck next time they have a similar issue. Instead, if you are going to provide code, explain it, and describe how their code is problamatic and why you made the changes you did

Comment: @ItsMeNaira the issues with the code were already mentioned by others in their comments, and I already put the description of the code as in-line comments